# Good examples of tensor products for beginners.

Tags: examples-counterexamples, tensor-products

Here is my question: If you were to make a presentation that require the use of tensor products (let's say for commutative rings) but your audience may not know about tensor product.

Since it is a short presentation, you would define it by its basis and properties of bilinearity:
$$(a \cdot x + x') \otimes_A (b \cdot y + y') = ab \cdot (x \otimes y) + a \cdot (x \otimes y') + b \cdot (x' \otimes y) + (x' \otimes y')$$
And then shortly explain why it is useful for bilinear functions.

But let's be honest, at least half of **the audience won't get it without a good explicit example**, here is what I had in mind:

- The complexification of a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $V$:
  $$V_\mathbb{C} := \mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} V$$
  which is very useful since you could also try to explain a bit of adjunctions properties of the tensor product by quickly explaining why
  $${V_\mathbb{C}}^\ast \simeq \hom_{\mathbb{R}} (V, \mathbb{C})$$
- The "gcd" tensor product:
  $$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}/(n \wedge m)\mathbb{Z}$$
  Which simply seems right for me, the proof uses the simple mechanics of tensor product in their entirety.

---

**EDIT:**
Two more interesting examples have arisen in the comments:

- The “kronecker” tensor product:
  $$\mathbb{R}^n \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{R}^m \simeq \mathbb{R}^{nm}$$
  Which seems relevant since it gives the dimension of the tensor product for vectors and matrices and gives credit to the kronecker product.
- The “field ($\text{char} =0$) vs torsion” tensor product:
  $$ \mathbb{Q} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \simeq \{0\}$$
  Which puts in light the need for compatibility of the torsions of both modules (like the gcd tensor product did).

---

**What do you think about these two examples? Do you have other example that are worth a little screen time in this presentation?**

If this is a duplicate, I will kindly delete it but keep in mind that I don't want an explanation of what tensor products are, I'm at ease with them :)

Comment: Maybe $\Bbb R^n\otimes\Bbb R^m\cong\Bbb R^{nm}$ is of interest? Makes the Kronecker vector/matrix product make sense

Comment: @FShrike Yes, this is a good and not too complicated example (I forgot about it) thank you!

Comment: There's also $\Bbb Q\otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z = \{0\}$, which is like the gcd example but even a little simpler.

Comment: Right, torsion and fields don't work well together... thanks too @GregMartin

Comment: (Well, fields of nonzero characteristic have no problem with torsion.)

Comment: Two possible examples come to mind: Show that the space of linear maps $L: V \rightarrow W$ is naturally isomorphic to the tensor product $W\otimes V^*$. I also prefer to define tensor products of dual spaces n terms of multilinear functions on $V^*$. Then an interesting tensor is the trace function on $V\otimes V^*$.